# Discord bot random react on embed

Tags: python, discord.py

Im making a mini game in Discord where the bot will make a random react on a embed. I tried to use the code (random react:). I dont get any errors when trying to run the code but when I use the command the random react dont get reacted by the Discord bot.

Could someone help on how to make the bot send random react on a embed?

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
    async def playbs(self, ctx):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="**BEATSABER**",
                              colour=discord.Colour.dark_red())
    
        embed.add_field(
            name="*HOW TO PLAY:*",
            value=
            "Under this message is many reacted emojis. In the middle you have 4 arrows. 1 arrow that points up 1 that ponts down and 2 that points on left and right."
        )
        embed.set_footer(text="Made by: Jellie")
        embed.set_thumbnail(
            url=
            "https://i.imgur.com/keLKx3H.png"
        )
    
        msg = await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
        await msg.add_reaction("<:gray_cube1:1000731095437934672>")
        await msg.add_reaction("<:up:959720228407894056>")
        await msg.add_reaction("<:right:959720161156407308>")
        await msg.add_reaction("<:left:959720190730436608>")
        await msg.add_reaction("<:down:959720112808673370>")
        await msg.add_reaction("<:gray_cube2:1000731117445464125>")
```

> random react:

```
        r = random.choice(["up", "left", "right", "down"])
      
        if r == (["up"]):
          await msg.add_reaction(":green_square:")
    
        if r == (["left"]):
          await msg.add_reaction(":green_square:")
    
        if r == (["right"]):
          await msg.add_reaction(":green_square:")
    
        if r == (["down"]):
          await msg.add_reaction(":green_square:")
```

Comment: Use `r=="up"` instead. `r` will be a string, not a list containing a string

Comment: Also your reaction in all 4 cases is the same

Comment: @mousetail ik that all of the random reacts is the same thats bc im teting the feature. That will get changed when the feature works.

Comment: @mousetail you mean that I should change the "if r == (["up"]):" to "if r=="up":

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try printing the value.

```
f = random.choice(["A", "B"])
print(repr(f)) # repr gets a more detailed view of what a variable actually is.
# prints "A"
print(repr("A" == ["A"])) # prints False, they are not equal
print(repr("A" == "A")) # prints True, same type
```

So you can fix your `if` statements like this:

```
r = random.choice(["up", "left", "right", "down"])
      
if r == "up":
   await msg.add_reaction(":green_square:") 
elif r == "left":
   await msg.add_reaction(":green_square:")
elif r == "right":
   await msg.add_reaction(":green_square:")
elif r == "down":
   await msg.add_reaction(":green_square:")
else:
   # Cause a error if the emoji is not found, help prevent undefined behavior in case of a typo
   raise ValueError(f"Unexpected value for r: {r}")
```

### Alternate Cleaner Solutions

However, you can do this much cleaner. There is no need to use any if at all here.

```
await msg.add_reaction(
     random.choice([
         "<:gray_cube2:1000731117445464125>",
         "<:red_cube>"
    # add any more emojis here
    ])
)
```

If you do need to know the direction maybe for later in the code you can do this, using a dict instead:

```
emojis_for_directions = {
    "left": ":green_square",
    "right": ":red_square",
    # add any more emojis here
}

r = random.choice(["left", "right"])
await msg.add_reaction(emojis_for_directions[r])
```